# Do I have to convert my website project into a web application project to migrate to Azure?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I have a current website project that I need to migrate to Windows Azure. Back in 2009 we had to convert the website project to a web application project. Is that still the case today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your life will probably be a lot easier if you use web application projects, but you *can* use website projects. At the very least, you can use cspack from the command line and point it at any directory. You can also use the physicalDirectory attribute in ServiceDefinition.csdef to point to an arbitrary directory. That directory can be your website project.

I'm not sure if there are better ways from within Visual Studio to use a website project as a web role.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any project to the Windows Azure Visual Studio project. I like to create a new Windows Azure project first, and then add existing projects to it (rather than the other way around).

Comment: Including Website projects instead of web application projects?

Comment: Either one works, but you would be better off with a web application. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) goes into more detail about the differences between the two.